# Scale convolution decomposition of a density

Tags: probability-distributions, integral-transforms

Is it possible to decompose the density:

$$p(x) = \frac{8}{\,\pi^2} \frac{x^3\tanh(x)}{\cosh^2(x)},\quad x>0$$

into a scale convolution of two non-negative densities: $p(x) = \int_0^{\infty} \xi^{-1}f(\xi^{-1}x)g(\xi)d\xi$ ? The Mellin transform of a scale convolution is the product of the Mellin transforms, so decomposing the Mellin transform into a product can produce a scale convolution representation. I believe the Mellin transform of $p(x)$ is:

$$\zeta(s+1)\,\Gamma(s+3)\,(2^{-s}-4^{-s})$$

The Riemann Zeta function arises as a Mellin transform of the Jacobi theta function, and the discontinuous Engel map. Possibly the Legendre duplication formula could be used on the Gamma function, and the density could be represented as a scale mixture of $x^k\exp(-x^2)$, but I'm not sure how to formulate a decomposition into a product of functions with convergent inverse Mellin transforms.

Or is there another type of real valued integral representation of this density?

This density is the scale mixing density of a representation of the $h(x) = \log \cosh(x) $ function in terms of the piecewise quadratic and linear Huber loss function (actually $p(x) = -x^3h'''(x) = -x^3 D^2 \tanh(x) $).

If the scale mixing density can be decomposed, then it may be possible to represent $\log \cosh$ as a scale mixture of a more well behaved function, which might possibly be used to prove an inequality regarding this function.

Comment: _"is there another type of real valued integral representation of this density?"_ how about: $g(\xi)=\delta(\xi-1)$, $f(x)=p(x)$

Comment: @CarloBeenakker cheeky. By "other" I meant an e.g. ordinary convolution (not with a delta function!) or other integration with another type of kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very profficient with scale convolutions, so I turned this problem into normal convolutions. I guess this is not the most straightforward way, but here it is:

The scale convolution reads
\begin{equation}
p(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\xi}f(x/\xi)g(\xi) d \xi
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x e^{-t'})g(e^{t'}) d t' 
\end{equation}
For $x=e^{t}$
\begin{equation}
p(e^{t}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(e^{t-t'})g(e^{t'}) d t'
\end{equation}
Let
\begin{equation}
P(t) = p(e^{t})\,,\qquad F(t) = f(e^{t})\,,\qquad G(t) = f(e^{t})\,.
\end{equation}
We then get an ordinary convolution
\begin{equation}
P(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(t-t')G(t') d t'\,.
\end{equation}
Fourier-transforming $\tilde X(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int d t e^{i \omega t} X(t)$, the convolution turns into a product
\begin{equation}
\tilde P(\omega) = \tilde F(\omega) \tilde G(\omega) \,.
\end{equation}
Then, given a $G$, we can find $F$ through
\begin{align}
F(t') &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int d\omega e^{-i \omega t'}\frac{1}{\tilde G(\omega)}\int d t e^{i \omega t} P(t) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
\int d t
P(t'-t)
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int d\omega \frac{1}{\tilde G(\omega)} e^{-i \omega t}  
\end{align}
Let's take
\begin{equation}
G(t) = \theta(-t)\frac{e^{t/\tau}}{\tau}\,,
\end{equation}
where $\theta(t)$ is Heaviside step function, the Fourier transform of which is
\begin{equation}
\tilde G(\omega) = \frac{i }{\sqrt{2 \pi } (-\tau  \omega +i)}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int d\omega \frac{1}{\tilde G(\omega)} e^{-i \omega t}
=2 \pi  \delta (t)-2 \pi \tau \delta '(t)
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
F(t')
=
\frac{8}{\pi^2}\left[\pi  e^{3 t'} \operatorname{sech}^4(e^{t'}) \left((1-3 \tau ) \sinh (2 e^{t'})+2 \tau  e^{t'} \left(\cosh(2 e^{t'})-2\right)\right)
\right]
\end{equation}
which is positive for $0<\tau<1/4$ (I don't have good proof for that, but I'll make an update if I find one; right now I make this assertion by checking it numerically). In terms of original variables:
\begin{equation}
g(x) = \theta(-\log(x))\frac{e^{\log(x)/\tau}}{\tau} = \theta(1-x) \frac{x^{1/\tau}}{\tau}\,,\qquad
f(x) = 
\frac{8}{\pi^2}\left[\pi  x^{3} \operatorname{sech}^4x \left((1-3 \tau ) \sinh (2 x)+2 \tau  x \left(\cosh(2 x)-2\right)\right)\right]\,.
\end{equation}
In the limit $\tau\rightarrow 0$, this tends to Carlo Beenakker's elegant solution ;).

Here's a plot of $f$ for different values of $\tau$:
[image]

Comment: Is that the Jacobi theta function? Is $g$ it a density? What is the domain?

Comment: $\theta$ is Heaviside step function. $g$ is positive for $x>0$.

Comment: According to Maple, your $f$ simplifies to $\frac{8x^3}{\pi\cosh^4(x)}$, independent of $\tau$.

Comment: This must be a mistake. It certainly depends on $\tau$.

Comment: Yes sorry, I left out a multiplication sign but it didn't complain.

Comment: Btw, I'm not vouching for all the $2\pi$ factors being correct. I'll check it later.

Comment: Ok assuming it's correct, I think that will actually work for me to represent $\log \cosh$ in terms of a nice piecewise twice differentiable function. You just need to divide $f$ by $2\pi (\tau+1)$ and multiply $g$ by $\tau+1$.

Comment: Actually this is pretty straightforward in the Mellin domain. E.g. for $\tau = 1/4$, the Mellin transform of $g$ is $1/(s+4)$.  The inverse transform of $(s+4) \tilde{p}(s)$ is $4p(x)-x p'(x)$, which gives $f(x)$. $f(x)$ can be shown to be positive by converting the density to $x^3( 3x\tanh(x) + \tanh(x) - x)/\cosh^2(x)$ and use $\tanh(x) \ge x/\sqrt{x^2+1}$ and then show this function is increasing.

Anyway, thanks, I was thinking this was unlikely to work, but then it actually works out as I was hoping.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad this was useful